# I can't convert my datetime format in the View of a ASP.NET MVC 5. Application. How do I solve it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, view

I'm trying to change the datetime format of my @Html.EditorFor but I can't. 
I'm trying to do it by the data annotations.

That's the code of my Model.

```html
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Dominio_FlowerMorena.Entidades
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    public partial class Tabela_Participante
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Tabela_Participante()
        {
            this.Tabela_Participante1 = new HashSet<Tabela_Participante>();
        }
    
        public long ID_Participante { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string CPF { get; set; }
        public string RG { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Data de Retorno")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Data em formato inválido")]
        public System.DateTime Data_Nascimento { get; set; }
        public string Sexo { get; set; }
        public string Estado_Civil { get; set; }
        public int Numero_Dependentes { get; set; }
        public long FK_Endereco { get; set; }
        public string E_mail { get; set; }
        public string Telefone { get; set; }
        public string Celular { get; set; }
        public string Operadora { get; set; }
        public long FK_Conta { get; set; }
        public string Segundo_Titular { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> FK_Patrocinador { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Tabela_Conta Tabela_Conta { get; set; }
        public virtual Tabela_Endereco Tabela_Endereco { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Tabela_Participante> Tabela_Participante1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Tabela_Participante Tabela_Participante2 { get; set; }
        public virtual Tabela_Usuario Tabela_Usuario { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Ant That's my View code:

```html
@model FlowerMorena_WebUI.Models.ViewModelFicha

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CadastrarFicha";
}

<h2>CadastrarFicha</h2>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>RsvpForm</title>
        <link href="~/Content/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center"><h4>Participante</h4></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary();
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Nome do participante: </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Participante.Nome, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Segunda titular: </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Participante.Segundo_Titular, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> CPF: </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Participante.CPF, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> RG: </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Participante.RG, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>  Sexo: </label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Participante.Sexo, new[] {
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Masculino",
                    Value = "M"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Feminino",
                    Value = "F" }
               }, "Sexo", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Operadora: </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Participante.Operadora, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Celular: </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Participante.Celular, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Telefone: </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Participante.Telefone, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div><br/>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Estado Civil: </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Participante.Estado_Civil, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label> E_Mail: </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Participante.E_mail, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label> Número de dependentes: </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Participante.Numero_Dependentes, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label> Data de Nascimento: </label> <br />
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Participante.Data_Nascimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) <br/>
  
                </div>





                <div class="text-center">
                    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Cadastrar Paricipante" />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using the Data Annotations in Data_Nascimento field but the view is not applying the correct format. I want 'yyyy-MM-dd' and View returns to me 'MM-dd-yyyy'. How do I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Is this date field nullable?

Comment: What do all those other properties in your model and view have to do with your question. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you generating the HTML-5 datepicker using Chrome or Edge?

Comment: In Opera I got a different format but it is not still the DisplayFormat specified.

Comment: @PauloJ, The `EditorFor()` method applied to a property with `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` generates `<input type="date" ... />` which generates the browsers HTML-5 datepicker. But its only supported in Chrome and Edge. In other browsers it will display a normal textbox. In Chrome and Edge in will generate a datepicker but the whole purpose of that datepicker is to display the date in the browsers culture so if its `en-US` it will display `MM/dd/yyyy` but if its `en-UK` it will display `dd/MM/yyyy` (and it will always post back in the ISO format - `yyyy-MM-dd` so it binds correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to when you are actually outputting an existing value (i.e. after a POST has occurred or when displaying existing data) or when you are actually setting the value initially?

Your actual `[DisplayFormat]` attribute appears correct :

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
```

If you wanted to display the contents in another format, you could just adjust the `DataFormatString` as seen below :

```
// Display as "yyyy/MM/dd"
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
```

So if you don't have a predefined value for your `Data_Nascimento` value, this should render a TextBox with an initial value of `0001-01-01` :

[image]

If you were to simply submit this form, your model should be populated with the DateTime that corresponds to this, which if you executed a `ToString()` call on, would look like :

[image]

So the appropriate values are being posted properly as seen in [this interactive example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x6g6b3). So nothing really jumps out as being "wrong" within the current View that you provided, however **it's important to remember that DateTime objects are ignorant of any formatting rules, so if you are using the Visual Studio debugger and see "4/4/2016", this doesn't mean that your DateTime object is formatted as such**.

Comment: Hi Rion. Thanks for your explanation. However, I wanna that the user see the format YYYY/MM/DD in form. Is it possible? I tried to use the ToString() but it returned to me a error message.

Comment: If that is the case, then you could just change your `[DisplayFormat]` attribute to use that specific format like `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}"`. You can see an example reflecting those changes [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UhTM5j).

Comment: Rion, I already changed it in my code. Have you seen my first example(The model)?

Comment: It should be working as expected if you changed the DataFormatString property. .NET will use this format to determine how your specific DateTime value is formatted as the [previous example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x6g6b3) that I used demonstrated.

Comment: I changed the DateFormatString but it's not working. Really, I don't know what's is going on.

Look at it. 
       
        '[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]'

I'm getting different results in each different browsers. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Another option that you could consider using, since this may be related to the use of `EditorFor()` would be to use the `TextBoxFor()` helper to see if that might help alleviate the issues.